# Definition of second topological $K$-group of a Banach algebra

Tags: general-topology, operator-algebras, fundamental-groups, topological-k-theory, k-theory

The question is a about the definition of the second topological $K$-group of a Banach algebra $A$.

I was reading a [text](http://math.unice.fr/~indira/papers/Valette.pdf) of Alain Valette (Prop. 3.3.7) where he proves that 
$$
 K_1(SA) \cong \pi_1(\mathrm{GL}_\infty(A),1).
$$
Here $A$ is a Banach algebra and $K_1(A) = \mathrm{GL}_\infty(A) / \mathrm{GL}_\infty(A)_0 \cong \pi_0(\mathrm{GL}_\infty(A))$. By $\mathrm{GL}_\infty(A)_0$ one denotes the path component of $1$. The proof goes as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
 \pi_1(\mathrm{GL}_\infty(A),1) & \cong \pi_0(S\mathrm{GL}_\infty(A)) \\
 & \cong \pi_0(\mathrm{GL}_\infty(SA)) \\
& \cong K_1(SA) 
\end{align*}
$$
I am concerned about the following:

1. Why is $\pi_0(S\mathrm{GL}_\infty(A))$ a group ?
2. What are the first and second isomorphism ?

Remark: This whole question allows us to define
$$
 K_2^{\mathrm{top}}(A) := \pi_1(\mathrm{GL}_\infty(A),1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your questions reveal a typo that Valette was not aware of. The third line of the proof of Proposition 3.3.7 should be:$$\pi_n(\text{GL}_\infty(A))  = \pi_{n - 1}(\Omega \text{GL}_\infty(A)) = \pi_{n - 1}(\text{GL}_\infty(SA)),$$where $\Omega X$ is the loop space of $X$. The first equality is a basic property of loop spaces, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_space). The second follows by observing that a loop in the invertible group of $A$ is the same thing as an invertible element in the suspension of $A$ — there are some minor checks regarding units of algebras, but it works.